# Weird ASP.NET (MVC) error: "Unable to load one or more of the requested types."

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm getting weird error and I have no idea how to resolve it. I've got an ASP.NET MVC website which works fine but once I publish it to a server I get:

> "Unable to load one or more of the
>   requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information."

Stack Trace:

> [ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable
>   to load one or more of the requested
>   types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions
>   property for more information.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers) +206
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState
>   state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +188 
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +295 
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetPipelineApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +56
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +231
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to
>   load one or more of the requested
>   types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions
>   property for more information.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +8889839
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +85
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +333

I was trying to google some solution but so far have not found anything. 
The website has quite a lot of references which is most probably the cause of this problem, however I have no idea how to identify the problematic assembly.
The website runs on a subdomain, root site is also ASP.NET MVC app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation I was able to track the problem to (Fluent) NHibernate. It was not able to initialize itself due to security constraints on the server (read Medium Trust). 
First I tried to update to latest version hoping it would work in medium trust environment. Then I tried to patch it to work and then I just simply gave up and contacted my hosting provider to raise the trust level for the app.

Comment: That's great that your hosting provider would even do that.  However there is good news for us all and that Medium Trust is being phased out by Microsoft - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849801/is-trying-to-develop-for-medium-trust-a-lost-cause