# Entity Framework 6 and System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission under godaddy medium trust level

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to deploy an application to godaddy. 
My hosting version ASP.Net 4.0/4.5.
On http://onpremlab.com/
it works fine on my local environment.
Build with VS 2013 Preview for web and EF 6.0 Beta.

But when deployed throws

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type    'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission,
```

I have deployed another application to godaddy built in VS 2012 with EF5.0
That works perfect.

Is there any change in EF 6.0 thats Causing it.
I searched about it and found about godaddy medium trust level is there any workaround for it for EF 6.0

Another point is this project is deployed in a sub folder of hosting account if it makes any difference.

Update..

Stack Trace:

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Delegate.DelegateConstruct(Object target, IntPtr slot) +0
   Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader..ctor() +47
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +66
   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +106
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +418
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Thanks. Does not seem like EF but I will route this question to the owners for investigation.

Comment: Please note that if you are using Ninject, you will get a `Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission'` error instead, but it is resolved by the same answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Owin does not support medium trust anymore - take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849801/is-trying-to-develop-for-medium-trust-a-lost-cause/17218344#17218344) post for more details.

Comment: What is a solution to my problem.. ?

Comment: I don't know :(. Sorry.

Comment: Do you think explicitly defining   <trust level="Full" />  in web.config might help??? I am waiting for godaddy's FTP manager to load.

Comment: I am not sure. You can try...