# MVC5 fails on 1 and 1 Internet shared hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

My MVC4 sites work without problems on 1 and 1 Internet shared hosting, but when I tried MVC5's default site using the VS2013 beta, it failed and I haven;t been able to figure out why. Can anyone help? Here are the error messages:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

> Security Exception 
>    Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the >security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your >system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type >'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, >Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. >Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the >exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type >'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, >Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
>     System.Delegate.DelegateConstruct(Object target, IntPtr slot) +0
>     Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader..ctor() +47
>     Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +66
>     System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, > Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
>     Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +106
>     System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, >HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +418
>     System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] >handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>     System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, >HttpContext context) +336
>     System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296
>
> ---
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET >Version:4.0.30319.18044

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET team has killed support for medium trust.  MVC 5 now requires full trust.  See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17218344/59641 for more information.

Ask your hoster to run your site in full trust, or choose a different hoster.

Answer (score 8):

In general, most applications should run fine under Medium Trust. If your application requires Full Trust, you can override the trust level at the application level by adding the following to your web.config file:

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web> 
    <trust level="Full" /> 
  </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Works for me on GoDaddy shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Do they support ASP.NET 4.5.1 yet? The default MVC 5 template uses ASP.NET 4.5.1 which is still in beta as well. Can you target your project to the current ASP.NET 4.5 or 4?