# What FileIO permissions do you normally have in Medium Trust?

Tags: asp.net, security, hosting

This seems to be a problem I bump into again and again - how to find out whether a specific function is allowed in a given Trust Level.  I think MSDN should have this right up there with the class hierarchy for the function.  Anyway, rant over...

Can anyone tell me what the normal file access permissions are for the application folder (and subfolders) in Medium Trust?  My understanding is that you can read, execute and list, but can you modify and write?

Apologies if this basic information is readily available, but I haven't been able to find a straight answer to this question.

Kind wishes ~ Patrick

Comment: I have just discovered that the following code fails on my local machine running Medium Trust: FileStream f = File.OpenRead( @"/robots.txt" );. This standard text file is clearly opened by other parts of the same code, so why could my code be failing?  Bit stuck here.  Really hoping someone can suggest a way forward with this. - Patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have access to your application directory and its subdirectories.  The reason that particular command is failing is that "/" maps to the root of the hard drive, so you're actually trying to open "C:\robots.txt", which is forbidden.  You'll want to call `Server.MapPath("~/robots.txt")`, which will return "C:\full\path\to\robots.txt", then pass *that* into File.OpenRead.

Of course, since Medium Trust [is effectively dead at this point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17218344/59641), you should consider just running your site under Full Trust.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I actually worked it out myself after poking around for a couple of hours.  Stupid mistake.  Doh!  The article about Medium Trust being abandoned is, however, extremely interesting.  I regularly read several forums, but that didn't show up on my radar at all.  Thank you. - Patrick