# 1and1 Security Exception Issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, razor

I have bought a shared windows hosting plan from 1and1. Having uploaded the default Visual Studio "Web Pages" site, I am getting the following error on 1and1. Considering this is a default Microsoft template, I am very surprised to say the least.
I would appreciate any help that anybody is able to provide.
Many Thanks.

```
'Security Exception 
  Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the 
security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your 
system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 


     Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: 
Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, 
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error: 



Line 3:      <head>
Line 4:          <meta charset="utf-8" />
Line 5:          <title>@Page.Title - My ASP.NET Web Page</title>
Line 6:          <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
Line 7:          <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


 Source File:  e:\kunden\homepages\41\d516833426\www\_SiteLayout.cshtml    Line:  5 

Stack Trace: 



[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
   System.Web.HttpContext.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type service) +54
   System.Web.HttpContextWrapper.GetService(Type serviceType) +11
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlRewriterHelper.IsUrlRewriterTurnedOn(HttpContextBase httpContext) +108
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlRewriterHelper.WasRequestRewritten(HttpContextBase httpContext) +13
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath) +138
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath) +103
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrl(HttpContextBase httpContext, String basePath, String path, Object[] pathParts) +144
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Href(String path, Object[] pathParts) +44
   ASP._Page__SiteLayout_cshtml.Execute() in e:\kunden\homepages\41\d516833426\www\_SiteLayout.cshtml:5
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +199
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors) +69
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +131
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +90
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +233
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +80
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +63
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +267
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +98
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext) +171
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context) +66
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +5
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69




Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18055'
```

Comment: Does you account at 1and1 permit asp.net type sites?

Comment: This is precisely the experience I just had, so obviously you weren't able to convince them to change their policy. Think I'm going to look elsewhere for ASP.Net hosting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hoster (1and1) forces sites to run in Medium Trust.  Medium Trust is obsolete, and ASP.NET no longer supports it going forward.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17218344/59641 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2698981 for more information.

You could try convincing 1and1 to run your site in Full Trust.  Otherwise you should consider moving to a new hoster that allows Full Trust.

Comment: Yes, fully agree with Levi. It is permission issue. Please ask your hosting provider to grant full permission for you.