# asp.net mvc 5 entity framework 6 identity working with trust level = medium?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

Creating the simplest project (In visual studio 2013 -> asp.net web application -> MVC authentication with individual accounts), it works perfectly on localhost. However, when sending to the server (medium trust level), the project does not work when I try to enter login.

See the error image:
http://s18.postimg.org/fm2qw8gzt/print.png

I tried to include on assembly.cs [assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]. It did not work. I have created a strong name key. It did not work.

The server does not support level = full trust.

Do not believe there need to be full, because few asp.net mvc 5 sites would work on common servers.

Any idea?

Comment: ASP.NET now only supports full trust [Refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347092/deploying-asp-net-mvc-project/25354496#25354496)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is trying to develop for Medium Trust a lost cause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849801/is-trying-to-develop-for-medium-trust-a-lost-cause)

Answer (score 2):

The component "Identity" from Microsoft needs server with "Full Trust" Level to run.

Check Answer from Levi.
[Visual Studio 2013 Web Forms Site doesn't work with trust level "Medium"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587797/visual-studio-2013-web-forms-site-doesnt-work-with-trust-level-medium)