# Trust level for components of the Default ASP.NET MVC project in VS 2015?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, medium-trust

I am having problems with required trust level with my web host using an ASP.NET MVC application created in VS 2015.

So I created a "dummy" application from the template (none of my own code - just the Home, About, Contact controller etc that are created by default) and web host is running in Medium trust level. I replicated it locally forcing it to medium trust level in web.config and get the following exception trace:

> System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly
>   asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand,
>   IPermission permThatFailed) +165
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object
>   assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand,
>   IPermission permThatFailed) +100
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet
>   grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, Object assemblyOrString,
>   SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException) +284
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(CompressedStack
>   cs, PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet
>   demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, RuntimeAssembly asm,
>   SecurityAction action) +70
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName) +70    System.RuntimeType.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
>   reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +40
>   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +30
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerInfo.get_IsCodeDomProviderTypeValid()
>   +10    System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetRecompilationHash(CompilationSection
>   ps) +2485
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.get_RecompilationHash()
>   +92    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDateInternal(Int64
>   cachedHash) +498
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(Int64
>   cachedHash) +53
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +133
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +674

Is it possible for me to run in Medium trust level for a MVC application, what about it is the message complaining about?

Web host said it can be increased to Full trust if needed, but I want to make sure it is actually required before requesting that.

Functionality will eventually be: get page contents (like blog posts) from a database and show .cshtml pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you app includes a reference to the entity framework you will need full trust

https://www.godaddy.com/help/do-your-hosting-accounts-support-mvc4-and-mcv5-applications-8999

Edit looks like Asp.Net requires full trust

[asp.net mvc 5 entity framework 6 identity working with trust level = medium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094169/asp-net-mvc-5-entity-framework-6-identity-working-with-trust-level-medium)

Comment: Thanks, I don't have a reference to EF, is there a reference anywhere for which references require which trust level?