# I/O permission issue in medium trust environment in ASP.Net hosting

Tags: asp.net, api, file-permissions, shared-hosting, medium-trust

I have hosted my site and API on share hosting plan(on bigrock server - hosting provider company)
Till now i have full trust so i never faced issue while storing and retrieving image from/to server. But recently they have change my trust and now they only gives medium trust (before hosting on bigrock i have check on godaddy as well. Godaddy gives medium trust so i had opted bigrock, but now both hosting provider are same for me)

- Alternate Option: I will store image in DB so that no trust level never comes in picture as image get store in DB, but unfortunately it will cause load on my API. As if i store image in DB, byte array will get transfer in API. So site/mobile platform will take long time to display data. (as of now i am passing just image url so page get loaded with information and image will load in other thread. So ultimately, user's do not need to wait long for getting just information)

I have hosted my web application on somename.domain.com while i have hosted api on somenameAPI.doamin.com

( My current R&D : Can I host both API and application in same folder? As I am accessing API for any connection with DB. I am facing issue to store image on server (store through API on server in some physical location and i retrieve that location and store that url in db for that record, so i can retrieve same image for that record)

Am I on right track ? Any other option / opinion will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: It is not recommended to store the images in database, rather, it would be easy to choose the Web Host with Full Trust Level .. here, you would find ASP web hosts using latest Microsoft technologies http://www.asp.net/hosting/home

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but [you can't run ASP.NET on medium trust anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849801/is-trying-to-develop-for-medium-trust-a-lost-cause).  Partial trust is [officially considered obsolete by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5tk9z76(v=vs.110).aspx).

Find a place that gives you full trust, or use a VPS.  The very fact that your host does not realize that partial trust is dead implies that you should not be using them.

It is still possible to sandbox ASP.NET websites.  However, this **must be done at the operating system level**.