# Full Trust and Medium Trust Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, full-trust, visual-studio-2015

My usual web site hosting provider changed its policy to allow only Medium Trust for hosted applications.

I used to use Visual Studio 2010. But developed a new application using Visual **Studio 2015**. Got a security error.

Just for testing tired to load and run an "almost empty" site, the one generated by Visual Studio 2015 when you start a new project (not the empty one, but all code Microsoft VS 2015 generated)

Like that :

```
File > New Project
ASP.NET Web Application Visual C#
ASP.NET 4.5.2 Templates
Web Forms
```

Same error !

I conclude something in the most **basic application generated by VS 2015** requires Full Trust !!!

Please, anyone knows what inside this basic initial VS2015 application requires full trust ?

Thank you in advance,
Ricardo Conte

Answer (score 4):

The current versions of ASP.NET now only support full trust and some hosting provider does not provide full trust. ASP.Net MVC 5 no longer support partial trust for `<trust level="Medium" />` you need to develop this application in MVC3 or MVC 4. for  more information please read this [ASP.NET Partial Trust does not guarantee application isolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17218344/6300200)