# ASP.NET Trust Level other than Full

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, medium-trust

### Background

My company hired a security firm to assess our website.  One of their recommendations was to run the site under minimal trust.  I believe this will be too restrictive, but I would like to use a trust level that is more secure that full trust.

### Problem

I created an empty ASP.NET application that I am running locally (IIS Express & IIS).  Whenever I configure it to run anything less than full trust, I get the following security exception.

[image: Security Exception]

### Questions

How do I run an empty ASP.NET application under High or Medium trust?  What could be causing the security exception above?

### Configuration

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  <trust level="Medium"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: You might want to check out the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849801/is-trying-to-develop-for-medium-trust-a-lost-cause