# Security Exception ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I made this app that runs fine on my local pc but I get the following error when I've uploaded it to my website:

> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please contact your system administrator or change
>   the application's trust level in the configuration file. Exception
>   Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

I searched around to solve this issue and found that adding the `<trust />` element to the root-level web.config would fix the issue. I checked what trust level I had configured on my website in the ASP.NET settings (in this case it was set to High) so I did this in the correct web.config:

```xml
<system.web>
    <securityPolicy>
        <trustLevel name="High" policyFile="web_hightrust.config"/>
    </securityPolicy>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

This hasn't fixed my issue and I'm left with no avenues to explore to try and solve this. Below is the stack trace that I am given with the above error

```
[SecurityException: Request failed.]
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +165
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +100
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, Object assemblyOrString, SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException) +284
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(CompressedStack cs, PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, RuntimeAssembly asm, SecurityAction action) +70
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +40
System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +30
System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerInfo.get_IsCodeDomProviderTypeValid() +12
System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetRecompilationHash(CompilationSection ps) +2175
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.get_RecompilationHash() +96
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDateInternal(Int64 cachedHash) +458
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(Int64 cachedHash) +51
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace in a code block to preserve newlines.

Comment: Check with your hosting provider if they support newest .net version.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an issue with your hosting provider running on partial trust, which is [no longer officially supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849801/is-trying-to-develop-for-medium-trust-a-lost-cause#17218344) by Microsoft. You should:

1. Confirm that your hosting provider is indeed using partial trust.
2. Insist that they remove it because it is no longer supported.
3. If they don't comply, find a new hosting provider that supports full trust.

Comment: I went back into the ASP.NET settings and they do have the `Full` option so I selected this and changed the web.config to: `<trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>` but I still the get the same error.