# Getting ServiceStack licensing error when .NET Trust level is not "Full"

Tags: servicestack

We were required to lower .NET trust level for our WEB application using ServiceStack.

However when .NET trust level is set to anything lower than "Full", ServiceStack fails to recognize the license. Here is the stack I got:

> LicenseException: This license is invalid. Please see servicestack.net or contact team@servicestack.net for more details. The id for this license is '2771']
>     ServiceStack.LicenseUtils.RegisterLicense(String licenseKeyText) +781
>     ServiceStack.Licensing.RegisterLicense(String licenseKeyText) +5

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: How do you declare your license key (Web.config, separate file...)?

Comment: Through Licensing.RegisterLicense(string); in Application_Start

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack isn't supported in non-Full trust environments which is also [deprecated in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17218344/85785).