"How to Transition ASP.NET Application from Full Trust to High Trust in a Shared Hosting Environment?"
I am deploying an ASP.NET application that currently runs in a full trust environment. The hosting provider supports high trust, but not full trust. I need to adjust my application to comply with high trust requirements.
My application is hosted on a shared environment using Plesk with AccuWebHosting. The environment supports high trust but not full trust.now they told me  i need to modify the parts of the code that are full trust ,How can I modify my code to ensure compatibility with high trust?
"Are there specific areas in ASP.NET applications that commonly need adjustment when moving from full trust to high trust?"
"How can I test my application effectively in a high trust environment before deployment?"

Totally waste of your time, as partial trust has been obsolete for years, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849801/is-trying-to-develop-for-medium-trust-a-lost-cause Your hosting provider need to adjust their documentation and security procedures if they still want to provide quality services.

I also published. But there is no such criteria. You can do some below changes.

In web.config files, contains  element. Then please add
    <trust level="High"/> 


Verify you assemblies which are present in web.config file. Ensure your <assemblies> section only
includes trusted assemblies.

Review any custom <configSections> and ensure they do not require permissions beyond what is available in high trust.


I hope this is helpful for you.
